# Redirecting with nested routes in koa with koa-router

Tags: node.js, redirect, routes, koa

How do I do redirects with nested routes using `koa-router`?

app.js:

```
var router = require('koa-router')();
var route1 = require('./routes/route1');
var route2 = require('./routes/route2');

router.use('/route1', route1);
router.use('/route2', route2);

app.use(router.routes());
```

route1.js:

```
var router = require('koa-router')();

router.all('/', function *() {
    router.redirect('/route2');
});

module.exports = router.routes();
```

route2.js:

```
var router = require('koa-router')();

router.all('/', function *() {
    this.body = "route2";
});
```

The above code results in the following error at runtime when navigating to `/route1`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  at Router.redirect (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/koa-router/lib/router.js:477:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/routes/support.js:54:12)
  at next (native)
  at onFulfilled (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
  at /Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5
  at Object.co (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:50:10)
  at Object.toPromise (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:118:63)
  at next (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:99:29)
  at onFulfilled (/Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:69:7)
  at /Users/colevarner/fullpower/node/motionxlive-koa/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I need to learn to read. I interpretted the `koa-router` docs to say `router.redirect()` was intended to be used within an HTTP verb function.

The correct usage is below:

```
//either this

router.redirect('/route1', '/route2');

//or regular koa redirect

router.all('/route1', function *() {
    this.redirect('/route2');
});
```